# How to use static variables with react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

With `const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)` I can create a variable `open` which is persisted over calls of a functional component.

But which hook can I use if I do not want a rerender when setting a variable?

I have a custom hook draft:

```
const useVariable = (initialValue) => {
  const ref = useRef();


  return useMemo(() => {
    ref.current = [initialValue, (newValue) => { ref.current[0] = newValue }]
  }, [])
}
```

But according to https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo I can not rely that useMemo is not called anytime again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank to @shubham-khatri I found a solution to my question. Just use the initialValue of the useRef hook:

```
const useVariable = initialValue => {
  const ref = useRef([
    initialValue,
    param => {
      ref.current[0] = typeof param === "function"
        ? param(ref.current[0])
        : param
}
  ]);
  return ref.current;
};
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/v3zlk1m90

Edit: To account for Christopher Camp's comment I added that also a function can be passed like in useState. See usage in codesandbox

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. The reason is that the `val` local variable never changes until the component rerenders. You can click that button 200 times and it will only increment by one.

You have to do something more like this: `const useVariable = initialValue => {
  const ref = useRef(initialValue);
  return [ref, newValue => {
    ref.current = newValue;
  }];
};` and then `setVal(val.current + 1);`.

Answer (score 4):

You can make use of `useRef` hook if you just want to store the some data in a variable and not re-render when the variable is set

```
const unsubCallback = useRef(null);

if(!unsubCallback) {
    unsubCallback.current = subscribe(userId)
}
```

Comment: I would like to create a custom hook which mimics the interface of `useState`. Something like `const [var, setVar] = useVariable(initialValue)`. Do you also know how to create that?